Expression: vector subscript out of range for ranking up system
I'm working on a project that imitates a Honorum in which employees gets promoted after meeting some requirements. The problem is I got an error saying "Expression: vector subscript out of range", to my understanding "index of eligible candidate is not matching the office this candidate is going to be selected from". It works without a problem sometimes.
When I checked the while loop given in below, I realized that chosenIndex was out of bounds for government[index - 1].representatives.
if (openSeats > 0) {
  // Get the office one rank below
  // PoliticalOffice& previousOffice = government[index - 1];

  std::vector<int> suitableCandidatesIndices;
  if (government[index - 1].representatives.size() > 0) {
    for (int candidateIndex = 0; candidateIndex < government[index - 1].representatives.size(); ++candidateIndex) {
      // Check if the representative meets the eligibility criteria
      if ((index == 1 && government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].entry &&
           government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].age >= 32 &&
           government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].yearsInServiceAsEntry >= 2) ||
          (index == 2 && government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].mid &&
           government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].age >= 35 &&
           government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].yearsInServiceAsMid >= 2) ||
          (index == 3 && government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].senior &&
           government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].age >= 46 &&
           government[index - 1].representatives[candidateIndex].yearsInServiceAsSenior >= 2)) {
        suitableCandidatesIndices.push_back(candidateIndex);
      }
    }
  }

  while (!suitableCandidatesIndices.empty() && openSeats > 0) {
    // Randomly select a representative from the pool of suitable candidates
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(
        0, suitableCandidatesIndices.size() - 1);
    int chosenIndex = suitableCandidatesIndices[distribution(generator)];
    Representative& chosenRep = government[index - 1].representatives[chosenIndex];

    // Assign the chosen representative to the current position
    switch (index) {
      case 1:  // Mid-level
        chosenRep.mid = true;
        chosenRep.entry = false;  // No longer an Entry-level
        chosenRep.yearsInServiceAsMid = 0;
        break;
      case 2:  // Senior
        chosenRep.senior = true;
        chosenRep.mid = false;  // No longer a Mid-level
        chosenRep.yearsInServiceAsSenior = 0;
        break;
      case 3:  // Executive
        chosenRep.executive = true;
        chosenRep.firstTermYear =
            currentYear;  // Record the year of first term as Executive
        chosenRep.senior = false;  // No longer a Senior
        break;
    }
    office.representatives.push_back(chosenRep);
    filledSeats++;

    // Remove the selected representative from the lower-ranking office
    government[index - 1].representatives.erase(government[index - 1].representatives.begin() +
                                     chosenIndex);

    // Decrease the count of open seats
    --openSeats;

    int indexToRemove = chosenIndex;
    auto iterator = find(suitableCandidatesIndices.begin(),
                   suitableCandidatesIndices.end(), indexToRemove);
    // Update the list of suitable candidates
    if (iterator != suitableCandidatesIndices.end()) {
      suitableCandidatesIndices.erase(iterator);
    }
  }
}

I'm either ignorant or too tired to see what to do for a fix. Please help

Your call to government[index - 1].representatives.erase(...) modifies the size of that vector, potentially rendering the latter parts of suitableCandidatesIndices out of bounds. Consider the case where suitableCandidatesIndices = [0,1] and government[index - 1].representatives.length() is 2.

OT: introduce some helper functions and - variables to reduce the long-ass expressions in your code. Also introduce an enum for index instead of using meaningless numbers like 1,2,3. The switch on index could be a promote method on whatever type chosenRep is.

When you have a problem like this back up the code and then take an axe to it, chopping off parts that aren't needed to reproduce the bug. Usually by the time you've had to trade the axe for a knife or scalpel to make finer cuts you've found the problem. If not, you have something really close to a [mre] and are in a better place to ask a successful Stack Overflow question.

The values of mid and senior might be a enum too? something like ´enum serve { entry, medium, senior, dead };´
The index-1 worries me, especially as I can't see from your code what it is set to, maybe zero?

The core problem in your code is that your removal of suitable candidates from the original array does not change the indexes of all remaining suitable candidates. This can lead to the latter elements of that vector pointing into empty space.
You can structurally prevent this by extracting the eligible representatives first, promoting people out of the eligible pool, and returning what is left.
First, some helper functions that are not related to the process of moving representatives around:
enum Level { Entry, Mid, Senior, Executive };

bool isEligible(const Level target, const Representative& r) {
    switch (target) {
        case Mid:       return r.entry  && r.age >= 32 && r.yearsInServiceAsEntry >= 2;
        case Senior:    return r.mid    && r.age >= 35 && r.yearsInServiceAsMid >= 2;
        case Executive: return r.senior && r.age >= 46 && r.yearsInServiceAsSenior >= 2;
        default: return false; /* unreachable */
    }
}

void promote(const Level l, Representative r) {
    // Assign the chosen representative to the current position
    switch (l) {
      case Mid:
        chosenRep.mid = true;
        chosenRep.entry = false;  // No longer an Entry-level
        chosenRep.yearsInServiceAsMid = 0;
        break;
      case Senior:
        chosenRep.senior = true;
        chosenRep.mid = false;  // No longer a Mid-level
        chosenRep.yearsInServiceAsSenior = 0;
        break;
      case Executive:
        chosenRep.executive = true;
        chosenRep.senior = false;  // No longer a Senior
        chosenRep.firstTermYear = currentYear;  // Record the year of first term as Executive
        break;
    }
}

The body of the promotion function then becomes:
if (!openSeats) {
    return;
}

// Get the office one rank below
PoliticalOffice& previousOffice = government[index - 1];

std::vector<Representative> eligible;
std::remove_copy_if(
    previousOffice.representatives.begin(),
    previousOffice.representatives.end(),
    std::back_inserter(eligible),
    [](const Representative& r) { return isEligible(index, r); });

while (!eligible.empty() && openSeats > 0) {
    auto it = eligible.begin() + std::uniform_int_distribution{0, eligible.size() - 1}(generator);

    {
        Representative& chosenRep = *it;
        promote(index, chosenRep);
        office.representatives.push_back(chosenRep);
        filledSeats++;
    }

    eligible.erase(it);

    // Decrease the count of open seats
    --openSeats;
}

// Return remaining representatives to the previous office
std::copy(eligible.begin(), eligible.end(), std::back_inserter(previousOffice.representatives));

Some tricks to take away from this:

Several functions from <algorithm> replace for loops to a single function call with a clear range.
The inner block around Representative & chosenRep = *it limits the lifetime of this variable and prevents you from accidentally using the representative after it has been promoted.
Converting index into an enum that describes what kind of representative it is.

